# What is SugarContext.init(this) in Sugar ORM

Tags: android, sugarorm

I am using Sugar ORM to save data locally. But there is something that i don't understand.

What is **SugarContext.init(this)** and **SugarContext.terminate()**?

What are these two funtion do? Can anyone explain it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

SugarContext works as a singleton class (only one instance of this class is allowed). 
- init create a new context or returns the object
- terminate, closes the connection to the SQLite "database"

Comment: can you tell something more about it's usage?

Comment: You should call it in every `Activity` class (`onCreate`), which requires access to the ORM (with a reference to the `Context` - `this`).